# Gltf и json. Декодирование строки буфера

Tags: c#, json, three.js, webgl

Существуют два простых метода для декодирования строки base64 (в С#). Хочу собрать json для формирования gltf, и закодировать свои координаты и позиции вершин в буфер. Для этого пытаюсь понять, как оно устроено по умолчанию. В туториале разбирается примитивный треугольник - 3 координаты. Чтобы создать свою строку Base64, нужно понять как она получена для этого примитива. Попытался декодировать, тщетно. Вопрос - как получается строка в свойстве uri:

```
"buffers" : [
    {
      "uri" : "data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=",
      "byteLength" : 44
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Чтобы эвристически узнать алгоритм декодирования, надо знать, что должно получиться. Декодировать что-то, если неизвестно что там лежит, очень сложно.

Comment: Что, как, зачем, почему, написано все в официальной документации, где есть именно ваш [пример](https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Tutorials/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_003_MinimalGltfFile.html), там и сказано как работает все это, сказано что в буфере солянка из разного набора данных, со своими смещениями и своими данными, за то что и как из буфера получать, отвечает `bufferViews`, в котором указан номер буфера, смещение, размер, тип, ну и также про 2 пустых байта между забывать не стоит. На хабре кстати есть [русский перевод](https://habr.com/ru/articles/448220).

Comment: рассчитывал на ответ людей, которые работали с gltf, поэтому не стал уточнять, сорри)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если раскодировать base64 и эвристически глянуть на этот массив в HEX формате, по можно увидеть следующее:

```
00000100020000000000000000000000000000000000803F0000000000000000000000000000803F00000000
```

Здесь внимание привлекают комбинации `0000803F` так как это `1` в формате `float`. Если представить, что в конце массива 3 трехмерных вектора, то тогда их можно раскодировать. А вот что представляют собой первые 8 байт массива - загадка. Без знаний, что именно там лежит и не заглядывая в спецификацию хранения данных - расшифровать это проблематично.

Вот код для начала

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = """
{
  "buffers" : [
    {
      "uri" : "data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAABAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAA=",
      "byteLength" : 44
    }
  ],
}
""";
        MyBuffer[] buffers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true }).Buffers;
        MyBuffer buffer = buffers[0];
        string uri = buffer.Uri;
        const string prefix = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,";
        if (uri.StartsWith(prefix))
        {
            string base64 = uri.Substring(prefix.Length);
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(bytes));
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(bytes[..8]));
            Vector3[] vertices = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, Vector3>(bytes[8..]).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vertices));
        }
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("buffers")]
    public MyBuffer[] Buffers {  get; set; }
}

public class MyBuffer
{
    [JsonPropertyName("uri")]
    public string Uri { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("byteLength")]
    public int ByteLength {  get; set; } 
}
```

Вот вывод в консоль

```
00000100020000000000000000000000000000000000803F0000000000000000000000000000803F00000000
0000010002000000
<0  0  0>
<1  0  0>
<0  1  0>
```

Но я бы начал с изучания glTF [спецификации](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/specification/2.0/Specification.adoc). Наверное в ней и хранится ответ на вопрос, что же там за числа и в каком формате лежат данные в первых 8 байтах массива.

Comment: Спасибо, в буфере лежат индексы вершин (0,1,2) и и координаты треугольника. Не знал, что данные хранятся в 16ой системе. Еще раз спасибо, помогли для дальнейших рассуждений!

Comment: @iDanilov это просто массив байт, двоичных данных. 16ричная система - всего-лишь удобный способ на них посмотреть в консоли.

Comment: касаемо 8 байт - индексы выражаются в ushort типе, поэтому 2 байта на вершину, 6 байт + 2 отступ до данных с координатами

Comment: @iDanilov `ushort[] indexes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(bytes[..6]).ToArray();`

Comment: помогите, я не представляю, как получить эту строку. в упор. направьте на путь истинный, как из 0.1 получить 0000803F. и битконвертеры, и просто конвертеры пробовал, тщетно. бит конвертер вообще почему-то в 64 битах переводит
кроме того, если получится одно число перевести байты, то как переводить последовательность координат(

Comment: почему-то при переводе через бит конвертер получаю 00 00 F0 3F

Comment: @iDanilov не используйте `BitConverter`, он устарел и его поведение зависит от типа процессора, используйте `BinaryPrimitives`. Получить просто создаёте массив, например `byte[] b`, если надо не в начало писать, то делаете `Span<byte> bs` например так `= b.AsSpan()[4..]` (это с отступом 4 байта) и пишете в него `BinaryPrimitives.WriteSingleLittleEndian(bs, f)`. `MemoryMarshal` это полезно, когда надо преобразовать массив из одного типа в другой без копирования данных при условии что формат чисел совпадает с системным (получите `Span`).